# Inner bevel in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a number of 2D shapes that interlock with no gaps. I can extrude them to 3D *without* a bevel and they continue to fit together correctly. However if I add a bevel when extruding, the shapes grow which means they overlap each other when adjacent:

[image: 3D render]

Here you can see that the top of red shape (translated +Z for clarity) is the same width as the gap in the blue shape but that the sides of the red shape have expanded.

Is there any way to achieve an inner bevel which doesn't change the shape's outer dimensions?

Comment: I'm thinking you are just going to have to look at the source code and see if you can hack something...

Comment: I'd create a function that recalculates the dimension, based on the bevel: width = width - (2*bevel)